# Where can I find a review of selection methods for evolutionary algorithms?

Tags: selection, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

Is there a review paper or some blog post which covers a significant share of all possible selection methods for evolutionary algorithms?

I've found some papers but they are covering only most popular selection methods such as roulette-wheel selection, stochastic universal selection, rank-based selection, truncation selection, tournament selection.

I want to find something that addresses other selection methods such as Boltzmann selection, reward-based selection, steady-state selection and hopefully some methods that I haven't heard about.

Comment: This might be more on-topic at https://or.stackexchange.com/ .